# java.lang.RuntimeException on Google console

Tags: android, runtimeexception, google-console-developer

I have an application ANDROID on the Play Store.
On Google Play console, I access to the ANR report and to the errors report.
Until now I had no anomalies. However, I recently discovered that when I set the filters to "installation from any source", I had 6 error reports.

First does it mean that my app is available "illegally"?

Second, I don't understand the error report. Can someone help me on the subject?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2778)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2856)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1589)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I think the error occurs before entering my application but I'm not sure

Comment: can you add full stacktrace

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only information I have in the Google console